# Javascript: get value from nested array of object and make it an object key

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of object like this

```js
{
  "data": [{
    "location": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        77.361916,
        28.606075
      ]
    },
  }]
}
```

I want to get the latitude and longitude from this and mutate the object to something like this:

```js
{
  "data": [{
    "latitude": 28.606075,
    "longitude": 77.361916,
  }]
}
```

How can i achieve this? I tried by doing

```js
response.map((data: any) => {
  console.log(data.location);
  let latitude = data.location.coordinates[2];
  let longitude = data.location.coordinates[1];
  delete data.location;
  data.latitude = latitude;
  data.longitude = longitude;
})
```

I know this is wrong but how can i fix this?

Comment: why is this wrong, except for the fact that array indexes start with `0` and not `1`?

Answer (score 2):

If you only have one set

```js
const oldObj = {
  "data": [{
    "location": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        77.361916,
        28.606075
      ]
    },
  }]
}
const [longitude, latitude] = [...oldObj.data[0].location.coordinates]
const newObj = {
  data: [{ latitude, longitude }]
}

console.log(newObj)
```

For more

```js
const oldArr = [{ "data": [{ "location": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 77.361916, 28.606075 ] }, }] }, { "data": [{ "location": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 77.361916, 28.606075 ] }, }] }, { "data": [{ "location": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 77.361916, 28.606075 ] }, }] } ]

const newArr = oldArr.map(item => {
  const [longitude, latitude] = [...item.data[0].location.coordinates];
  return {
    data: [{
      latitude,
      longitude
    }]
  }
})

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
response.map((data: any) => {
  let newData = {"data" : []};
  let coords = {
    'latitude' : data.location.coordinates[2],
    'longitude' : data.location.coordinates[1]
  }
  newData.data.push(coords)
  return newData;
})
```